# MySQL Query advice & joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables and need to do a query

```
Clubs( club_id, name )
Facilities ( id, club_id, name )
```

The logic is a club can have one or many facilities, I need a simple query to basically search all clubs that have certain facilities

eg. Get all clubs with football AND tennis court facilities

```
SELECT *
FROM (`clubs`)
JOIN `club_facilities` ON `club_facilities`.`club_id` = `clubs`.`id`
WHERE `facility_id` = 1
AND `facility_id` = 3
```

This brings back 0 results - however if change this to the following

```
SELECT *
FROM (`clubs`)
JOIN `club_facilities` ON `club_facilities`.`club_id` = `clubs`.`id`
WHERE `facility_id` = 1
OR `facility_id` = 3
```

I get two results (rows) from the db - I presume I would need to do some additional self-join but not entirely sure how to do this.. Can anyone give some suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: where do you need self join and what's the purpose.please elaborate your question little more.

Comment: @punit sorry i realise my question wasn't the clearest luckily i've sussed it with help from socha below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the facilities table twice.

```
SELECT * FROM clubs 
JOIN club_facilities f1 ON club_id = clubs.id
JOIN club_facilities f2 ON club_id = clubs.id
WHERE f1.facility_id = 1
    AND f2.facility_id = 3
```

Or use subselects:

```
SELECT * FROM clubs 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM club_facilities WHERE club_id = clubs.id AND facility_id = 1)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM club_facilities WHERE club_id = clubs.id AND facility_id = 3)
```

Comment: funny, thought exactly the same about your answer :)

Comment: @soch23, so it the human perception! ;-) (In terms of performance, though, I think I win).

Comment: awesome stuff! what a genius - this seems to work thanks socha :)

Comment: I used the subselects method as this seems better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT clubs.id FROM clubs JOIN club_facilities ON (club_id=clubs.id)
WHERE facility_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY clubs.id
HAVING count(DISTINCT facility_id)=2;
```

will get you clubs where the number of facilities matching `IN (1,3)` condition is 2 (i.e. both).